# Isotonic regression like

Tags: optimization, matlab, numerical-optimization

I have 2 ordered sets
$$X=\{X_1<\dots<X_n\}$$ and
$$Y=\{Y_1<\dots<Y_m\}$$ with $X_1<Y_1$ and and $X_n<Y_m$.
I wish to approximate an increasing continuous function $g$ by piecewise linear polynomials on knots $K_1<\dots<K_k$ such that
$$\ell=-\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\log(1+\lambda[g(Z_i)-1])+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(g(X_i))$$ where $\lambda$ is the solution of 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\frac{g(Z_i)-1}{1+\lambda[g(Z_i)-1]}=0$$ and
$$Z=X\cup Y.$$

I don't know yet either this problem has solution or not. I already tried using fmincon in matlab by initilizing $g$ as linear function. However, the result is far away from the true situation.
Any advice?

Comment: Off topic : I'm surprised why this question has little view after 15 days and after being in bounty in one week and has got no answers even no comments.

Comment: @Edi: I don't know why. May be it is not interesting?